# Excel : How to apply a criterion to each cell in an array?

Tags: excel

[image]

So in the example above, I would like to extract all cells that contain "A" as the first letter(and length=9, though it does not matter).
 Now I am able to run the function for one cell, but I want to run it as an array formula so that I do not have to drag down 1000 cells every time. Below is my code:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$3, IF(AND(LEFT(A2,1)="A", LEN(A2)=9), ROW($A$1:$A$3),"")),"")
```

The problem here is that when I enter the code with "Ctrl + Shift + Enter", the criteria would be only confined to A2, which is the cell address I manually entered. Is there anyway to check for every single cell without having to drag down WITHOUT USING VBA? I know using VBA would make it a lot easier, but I just want to understand the basics of Excel further.

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
=iferror(index(a:a, aggregate(15, 7, row(a:a)/(left(a$1:index(a:a, match("zzz", a:a)))="a"), row(1:1))), text(,))
'with 9 length criteria
=iferror(index(a:a, aggregate(15, 7, row(a:a)/((left(a$1:index(a:a, match("zzz", a:a)))="a")*(len(a$1:index(a:a, match("zzz", a:a)))=9)), row(1:1))), text(,))
```

Fill down as necessary.

If you only want the single left-most character from a string of text, you do not have to supply a 1; you can omit the *number of characters* argument.